# How to parse calendar date or timestamp at cursor from elisp?

Tags: calendar, parse-time

Is there a function to parse the text around the cursor and return the date if found?

E.g., if I'm in a buffer with the cursor in the middle of this text:

```
2015-12-01 First day of new exercise program
2016-01-08 Hit a milestone: ran a 7-minute-mile
```

and I want to use emacs to parse the dates and tell me the elapsed time between them, is there a function to help me do that?
Ideally it would handle full ISO timestamps also, e.g.

```
2016-01-08T08:13:55-0700
```

and of course other date formats.  Yeah - I know - it gets tricky, might need some hinting on formats, etc....

It looks like `date-to-time` can parse ISO strings, and `parse-time-string` can parse some formats, but not ISO.  But are there any functions to pick the right text from around the cursor?

See e.g. [Emacs Lisp: Parsing Date Time](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_parse_time.html)

Comment: See the the library **date-at-point**:  https://github.com/alezost/date-at-point.el  With that library (although I have never used it), you can probably do something like:  `(save-excursion (goto (point-at-bol)) [date-at-point applicable function])` and something similar for the next line, and then compare and contrast, etc. -- and of course, do your conversions along the way.

Comment: Cool.  It looks like the `thing-at-point` library and that tiny bit of code is the sort of thing I'm looking for, and could be extended to include timestamps.....